# setTimeout for Sping webServiceTemplate not working

Tags: java, spring, soap-client

I'm trying to set timeout for webServiceTemplate, but when I execute `marshalSendAndReceive()` the timeout ignores. Request takes about 5 second, but in coinfiguration I have set 5 millis. I tried to use `HttpComponentsMessageSender` instead of `HttpWebServiceMessageSenderBuilder`, but it also has no effect. So is there any way to solve this problem?

```
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setPackagesToScan(applicationProps.getPackagesToScan());
    return marshaller;
}

@Bean
public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate(final WebServiceTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.setMarshaller(marshaller()).setUnmarshaller(marshaller())
            .messageSenders(List.of(
                    new BasicAuthHttpsConnectionMessageSender(props.getUsername(), props.getPassword()),
                    new HttpWebServiceMessageSenderBuilder()
                            .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(5))
                            .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(5)).build()
            )).build();
}
```

Comment: You are setting multiple messagesenders, only 1 of them will be used, not both. I suspect you assumed they will be used both.

Comment: Oh, i was afraid that it is the problem. But is it posibble to set timeout for BasicAuthHttpsConnectionMessageSender?

Comment: I don't know the `BasicAuthHttpsConnectionMessageSender` class, so I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Here,

```
    new HttpWebServiceMessageSenderBuilder()
             .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(5))
             .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(5)).build();
```

You need to provide a large time duration i.e. `Duration.ofMillis(500)` now you can see the effect. So it is like

```
    new HttpWebServiceMessageSenderBuilder()
             .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(500))
             .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(500)).build();
```

The Duration of 5 `millis` is very short so you can't notice it.
See [here](https://hellokoding.com/spring-resttemplate-timeout/)

Comment: thanks, I will try.  But how can I combine this soulution with BasicAuthHttpsConnectionMessageSender? I mean I need to provide credentials for https connection, also I need a timeout. But I just found out that the only one of messagesenders will be used, not both

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using Duration.ofMillis(5) just use setConnectTimeout(5)

```
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
marshaller.setPackagesToScan(applicationProps.getPackagesToScan());
return marshaller;
}

@Bean
 public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate(final WebServiceTemplateBuilder 
  builder) {
return builder.setMarshaller(marshaller()).setUnmarshaller(marshaller())
        .messageSenders(List.of(
                new BasicAuthHttpsConnectionMessageSender(props.getUsername(), props.getPassword()),
                new HttpWebServiceMessageSenderBuilder()
                        .setConnectTimeout(5)
                        .setReadTimeout(5).build()
        )).build();
```

}

Comment: Those methods take a `Duration` not a regular `int`. This simply won't compile nor work.